# Edgar (finstr): error: cannot join on columns 'elementId' x 'elementId' - R

Tags: r, xbrl, edgar

Ran following: 
library(finstr)
inst<- "http://edgar.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312514383437/aapl-20140927.xml"

xbrl.vars<- xbrlDoAll(inst, verbose=TRUE)

st2013<-xbrl_get_statements(xbrl.vars)

Recevied following error

Error: cannot join on columns 'elementId' x 'elementId': Can't join on 'elementId' x 'elementId' because of incompatible types (factor / integer) 
In addition: Warning message:
In semi_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector

Comment: This was the solution  For now use options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) before calling xbrDoAll.
It is recommended in XBRL package (see ?xbrlDoAll) so finstr::xbrl_get_statements expects data frames without factors.

Example:

library(finstr)
inst<- "http://edgar.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312514383437/aapl-20140927.xml"

old_o <- options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xbrl.vars<- xbrlDoAll(inst, verbose=TRUE)
options(old_o)

st2013<-xbrl_get_statements(xbrl.vars)

Answer (score 0):

answer from **Darko Bergant**

For now use options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) before calling xbrDoAll.
It is recommended in XBRL package (see ?xbrlDoAll) so finstr::xbrl_get_statements expects data frames without factors.

Example:

library(finstr)
inst<- "http://edgar.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312514383437/aapl-20140927.xml"

old_o <- options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xbrl.vars<- xbrlDoAll(inst, verbose=TRUE)
options(old_o)

st2013<-xbrl_get_statements(xbrl.vars)